# Couldn't setState from the then function of the Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update the state from the `promise` which I received using the `fetch` function.

```
componentDidMount(){

fetch(url).then((responseText) => {

     var response = responseText.json();

     response.then(function(response){
         this.setState(response);
     });

  });
}
```

I was getting the error that the `setState` is not an function

Then, I tried to `bind(this)` to pass the `this` value like below.

```
componentDidMount(){

fetch(url).then((responseText) => {

     var response = responseText.json();

     response.then(function(response){
         this.setState(response);
     });

  }).bind(this);
}
```

It is not working now also. Same error again.

Answer (score 36):

This is because of the scoping of `this`, so you're on to something when you're trying to use `Function.prototype.bind`. Your mistake is that you don't bind all the way down to the last anonymous function. What you probably want to do is use arrow functions all the way, like this:

```
componentDidMount(){
    fetch(url)
        .then((responseText) => responseText.json())
        .then((response) => this.setState(response));
}
```

Arrow functions always keep the context of `this`.

Answer (score 14):

Sorry, Just now found that I didn't bind the `this` variable properly.

Now, It is fixed.

```
componentDidMount(){

  fetch(url).then((responseText) => {

    const response = responseText.json();

    response.then(function(response){
        this.setState(response);
    });

  }.bind(this));

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your second promise doesn't have the current `this` context. You can use an arrow function here as well.

```
componentDidMount(){
  fetch(url).then((responseText) => {
     return responseText.json();
  })
  .then((response) => {
     this.setState(response);
  });
}
```

Also, chaining instead of nesting your promises will help with the legibility and might help you to avoid [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You also have the wrong method to setState it should look something like setState({name : 'string'})