# How to pass url param to api in react component?

Tags: reactjs, api

I took the required param by using this.props.match.params.xyz from the URL and now I would like to pass it to the API. I don't understand how can I do it. Below is how I am trying to implement. It says the response is not defined.

```
componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://example.com/api/players?apikey=123&unique_id={`${this.props.match.params.xyz}`}')
        .then(response => response.json())
         console.log(response)     
       }
```

Comment: your console.log is outside of your promise- you may want to try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36693898/couldnt-setstate-from-the-then-function-of-the-promise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`response` is not defined because you're calling it outside of its scope. Try this:

```babel
fetch(
  `http://example.com/api/players?apikey=123&unique_id=${this.props.match.params.xyz}`
)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json));
```