# Dynamic dropdown list react axios get request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Inside of my main `App.js componentDidMount()` lifecycle phase I have an axios get request to a rest service.

EDIT: Included full `UserForm.js`

```
class App extends Component {
//  default state object
    constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        schemas: []
    } 
}


  componentDidMount() {
     axios
      .get('/dataschema/list')
      .then(response => { 
           console.log(response)
           this.setState({
               schemas: response
           });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error.response));
 }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">App</h1>
        </header>

        <LinkButton />
        <UserForm schemas={this.state.schemas} />

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This request is successful in returning an array of schemas(strings) (only 1 for now) in the console messages

```
Response:
{
    "data": [
        "Phone Record"
    ]
```

How can I populate this `UserForm.js` dropdown list with the `Phone Record` that was returned by the axios get request

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class UserForm extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {schemas: []};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.data});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('The dataschema you picked is: ' + this.state.schemas);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>
              Pick the dataschema to describe your data file:
                  <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
              { 
                (schemas && schemas.length > 0) && schemas.map((schema) => {
                  return (<option value="${schema.value}"> {schema.name}</option>);
                })
              }
              </select>
            </label>    
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default UserForm;
```

Comment: In your UserForm component, you are not accessing the schemas from props. See my answer below again. Make sure that you are passing the schemas to UserForm in your App component, and make sure that in UserForm's render() method you are retrieving the schemas array from props.

Comment: I have updated with my current changes

Comment: You have a typo in your App component, in `state`, `schemas` is plural. Should be `<UserForm schemas={this.state.schemas} />`

Comment: Was a copy and paste error, I have `schemas`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this, where the schemas are passed to the UserForm and the options for the select are rendered dynamically. I've filled out a little bit more of your code snippet, for context.

**UPDATED**: I fixed a few typos in the code snippet and provided a way for you to handle the schemas being undefined.

**NOTE**: This should head you in the right direction, you should be able to take this answer, and complete your work.

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {

    this.state = {
      schemas: []
    }
  }


  componentDidMount() {

    axios
      .get('http://localhost:port/api/rest/dataschema/list')
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        this.setState({
          schemas: response
        });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error.response));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">App</h1>
        </header>
        <LinkButton />
        <UserForm schemas={this.state.schema} />
      </div>
    );
  }

}

class UserForm extends React.Component {

  render() {

    const schemas = this.props.schemas;

    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Pick the dataschema to describe your data file:
              <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                { 
                  (schemas && schemas.length > 0) && schemas.map((schema) => {
                    return (<option value={schema}> {schema}</option>);
                  })
                }
              </select>
          </label>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you will have an error with setState in this way, see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36693898/couldnt-setstate-from-the-then-function-of-the-promise

Comment: Am getting `Type error: cannot read property 'map' of undefined` at this line `schemas.map((schema) => {` I think it's because the rendering of component occurs before the component receives the array.

Comment: You need to check that schemas is not empty / undefined. See my edits.

Comment: @ChadMoore that's what I thought

Comment: @ChadMoore `value` property now cannot be null

Comment: @ChadMoore I updated my post, there is nothing to be selected inside the drop down list now

Comment: Note, my use of schema.value and schema.name inside the map() function will probably not work for you. What exactly is schemas an array of? of strings? objects? What do you want the values of your select options to be? You will have to decide.

Comment: The schemas being return are in the format of strings in an array @ChadMoore

Comment: Updated the map() for an array of just strings.

Comment: hmmm I still can't get the dropdown list to be populated with `Phone Record`. I updated what the response data looks like the console

Comment: This is where coding gets painful. It's you and the code on the screen in front of you. You have to debug it. You are very close but you're going to have to take it from here. Start debugging! Doublecheck your HTML/JSX markup, play with the conditionals, console.log vars to see what value they have when render() is called. So and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to pass the records to UserForm

```
  componentDidMount() {
     const self = this;
     axios
       .get('http://localhost:port/api/rest/dataschema/list')
       .then(response => { 
            console.log(response)
            self.setState({ phoneRecords: response })
     })
     .catch(error => console.log(error.response));
   }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">App</h1>
        </header>       
        <LinkButton />
      <UserForm phoneRecords={this.state.phoneRecords}/>        
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Isn't this still a hard coded solution? I need a dynamic state to populate the dropdown list with all strings (schemas) in the array that are present when the get request to the rest service is performed.

Comment: @DJ2 no, because he just gets the date and passes by props, the hardcode lives inside UserForm right? The component which makes a request it's a container and he is don't know how this data is rendered he just pass on data.