# React Native setting state in promise when not Debugging

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise, remote-debugging

I am having some strange behavior with my app.
When I am debugging, my algorithm in componentDidMount, which consists of a long chain of promises, works fine for the most part.

However, when I am not debugging, a problem arises where I cannot set a state while in the promises. My code has a "loading" state that changes to false when data has been retrieved and my output is ready. This state is never changed.

I am partly concerned that the firebaseApp.database().ref()... is never being called. But there is not way to tell as I am not debugging. Is there a way to see if a function is being stepped into without using the debugger?

I have tried putting a setState({loading:false}); at the very top of my first promise call, but even then it does not change. If I put the setState call completely outside of the promise chain, it does work, but I cannot put it there as no data has been retrieved yet.

When debugging with chrome, however, this is not a problem and the state changes fine. I know there are some differences between the debugger and the native interpreter, such as: Date objects and comparator booleans. I am not sure what the problem might be here though.

Some code for reference:

```
let that = this;
    firebaseApp.database().ref("Restaurant_Tags").orderByChild("Author_ID")
                      .equalTo("test").once('value').then(function(snap){

          if(snap.val() != null){
            that.setState({loading:false});

firebaseApp.database().ref("Restaurant_Tags").orderByChild("Author_ID")                                 
.equalTo("test").once('value').then(function(snap){
    . . . etc
```

the

```
let that = this;
```

is because I was not able to access this within the promises. I have tried putting the set state directly below

```
let that= this;
```

and also within

```
firebaseApp.database().ref("Restaurant_Tags").orderByChild("Author_ID")
                      .equalTo("test").once('value').then(function(snap){
```

and of course, at the bottom of the algorithm where the data has been retrieved.

Does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: Take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36693898/couldnt-setstate-from-the-then-function-of-the-promise

Comment: That doesn't seem to do the trick. It still only works in the debugger

Comment: Have you tried catching any of these? side note I strongly suggesting using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function it is available in RN and it is so much saner than `.then` syntax, your brain will thank you

Comment: @Josh - Robbie has a point, you may want to put some catch's in there to see if you've got a network issue perhaps outside of a debugger environment.

Comment: `if(snap.val() != null) {...}` needs something like `else { throw new Error('snap.val() is null'); }`. With `.catch(...)` at the end of the chain, these errors, and others, will be caught.